# How to run sidekiq in background - what is the best approch with rails app running on Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, sidekiq-cron

I'm using `Sidekiq 6.0.1`.
I'm trying to run in the background, here is the command I'm using:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -L log/sidekiq.log -C config/sidekiq.yml -e development
```

This is showing

> > ERROR: Daemonization mode was removed in Sidekiq 6.0, please use a proper process supervisor to start and manage your services
> >
> > ERROR: Logfile redirection was removed in Sidekiq 6.0, Sidekiq will only log to STDOUT

My application is of **Ruby on Rails** and deployed using the **Nginx** web server.

What would be the best approach to run the `sidekiq` in the background so my **rails application** can run the `workers`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running on Linux, learn to use systemd.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#running-your-own-process